# fixed panels with scrollable content RICHFACES

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

Please tell me how can I create a Richfaces page where I want to keep the collapsible panels fixed and below that I have another form. As the form is very large. So I want to put a scroller. Do I need to use frameset or is there any support for that in Richfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing jsf-specific. That is usually done via CSS:

- create a `<div class="limitedHeightDiv">`
- define the css class in a css file:

  ```
  .limitedHeightDiv {
     height: 100px;
     overflow: scroll;
  }
  ```

(You can define these styles inline, using `style=".."`  as well)

Answer (score 1):

@Bozho

```
    .limitedHeightDiv {
       height: 100px;
       overflow: auto;
    }
```

Will work a way better, in the previous case you will have scroll bars even if you don't need them. I guess it is just a question of different design and flavors.
auto